# What command line tool is avialable to upgrade project files when using VS2010 Express edition?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-c++, msbuild

VS2010 Pro and better have the following:command line (Devenv /upgrade).
Below is the error I need to correct. There are around 36 library builds I need to upgrade and I would prefer to use a command line tool as mentioned in the error message below.

error MSB4192: The project file "vsprojects\libtcmalloc_minimal\libt
cmalloc_minimal.vcproj" is in the ".vcproj" file format, which MSBuild no longer
 supports. Please convert the project by opening it in the Visual Studio IDE or
**running the conversion tool,** or use MSBuild 3.5 or earlier to build it.

Answer (score 0):

Much simpler than I thought. But, still need devenv.exe (VS2010 Pro or better) to upgrade a solution file.

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vcblog/archive/2010/03/25/to-the-command-line-enthusiasts-some-quick-know-hows-for-upgrading-to-vs-2010.aspx